# Android-Studio: No build.gradle in my project, why?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am developing my android application on `Android-Studio`. My project was `checked out project from Git version control`. Everything works fine. Except that I cannot see `build.gradle` file. Hence I am unable to add modules or libraries.

1. Why doesn't my project has a `build.gradle` file ?!
2. Did I do anything wrong to import my project from Git ?
3. What should I do to be able to add libraries without having `build.gradle` ?

**Here is what I did to import my project:**

`Check out project from Version Control` -> `Git`,

after cloning, the following box appears:

[image]

I click `Yes. The follwoing box appears:

[image]

I accept the default options and click `Ok`, then the following box appear:

[image]

Again, I accept the default options and click `Ok`

Then my projec loads on `Android-Studio`. It shows me the following message:

[image]

Before I click on add root, the following box appears:

[image]

I click on `dont' remind me again for this project`. After that I can continue programming (Git and Version Control is working). But `build.gradle` is nowhere to be found !!

---

**UPDATE 1:**

The following image is the `project` view:

[image]

what am I doing wrong ?

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the `Android` view:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With huge help from **Stack Overflow** community, I figure out how to solve it. Here is what I did:

1. I totally removed `Android-Studio` following this [guidance](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uninstallreinstall-android-studio), then ...
2. I installed `Gradle` from this [link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/how-to-install-gradle-2.html), then ...
3. I re-installed `Android-Studio` following this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html):

I am gussing the main problem was that I didn't installed Gradle manually and hence `Android-Studio` was using some sort of Gradle-Wrapper to allow the application to run.

Now, finally I can edit `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 4):

> Choose Android View instead of Project View.. enjoy
>
> see image1

[image]

> see image2

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but don't you think I might have already tried changing the view. Anyway, I appreciate your answer, but I don't have as similar file structure as yours in image2. Mine is slightly different (please check the update)