# I don't have gradle.build, why?

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I am using `Android-Studio` to build my app. In order to add libraries, I need to edit `build.gradle` file but I don't see it anywhere. Even if I changed files-view from `android` to `project` and vice-versa .

Why don't I see/have `build.gradle` ?

Comment: did you imported the project from git/svn? or is it a fresh new project?

Comment: Yes, I imported it from git .. @JuLes

Comment: maybe they are in git ignore, and they were not pushed. Can you see the file on git?

Comment: Yes, I can see it on the online-git, as well as in the local project folder !! .. @JuLes

Comment: in my `.ignorgit` there is `.gradle/`, should I remove it ?! ... @JuLes

Comment: you could try, an try clicking on Gradle at the right side of the IDE and check there if you have the gradle file

Comment: I tried but still not working .. @JuLes

Comment: Where is "the Gradle at the right side" ?! I don't have it  @JuLes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128181/discussion-between-jules-and-suda-nese).

Comment: @JuLes : I got it to work. Thank you (please check my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With huge help from @JuLes (commentting on my question) I figure out how to solve it. Here is what I did:

1. I totally removed `Android-Studio` following this [guidance](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uninstallreinstall-android-studio), then ...
2. I installed `Gradle` from this [link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/how-to-install-gradle-2.html), then ...
3. I re-installed `Android-Studio` following this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html):

I am gussing the main problem was that I didn't installed Gradle manually and hence `Android-Studio` was using some sort of Gradle-Wrapper to allow the application to run.

Now, finally I can edit `build.gradle`.

BIG THANKS TO: JuLie

Answer (score 1):

Check in your git repository if it contains the `build.gradle` files.

If not, you can just add manually to your project.
You should have something like this:

```
root
|--app
|----build.gradle
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
```

You can also create a new blank project and copy the `build.gradle` files into your existing project (of course in the `app/build.gradle` file you have to change the values and the dependencies).

Comment: Yes, my online git repository already contains the `build.gradle`file.

Comment: As for full explnation of the problem please check this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40547859/2135363

Comment: You could also follow the continues discussion between JuLes and I in the comments above. Thanks